# What is exponentially fitted osculating straight line?

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, exponential-polynomials

While reading an article about iterative methods for solving nonlinear equations I can't understand what is *exponentially fitted osculating straight line*. Could someone please briefly explain this term to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's jargon for a function of the form
$$y(x)=e^{a(x-x_0)}[b(x-x_0)+c]$$
where the constants $a,b,c$ are determined such that $y(x)$ [osculates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_curve) the function $f(x)$ you are fitting to at $x=x_0$:

$$y(x_0)=f(x_0),\;\;y'(x_0)=f'(x_0),\;\;y''(x_0)=f''(x_0).$$

This gives

$$c=f(x_0),\;\;b+ac=f'(x_0),\;\;2ab+a^2 c=f''(x_0)$$

for example, see this [paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/JAM/Volume2012/294086.pdf)